# Redirecting Virtual User to Content Editor Programatically

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.5

I am trying to create a Virtual user with and redirect to content editor as below.

```
string userId = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", "sitecore", "testadmin");
var scUser = AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(userId, true);

scUser.RuntimeSettings.IsAdministrator = true;
scUser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Add(@"sitecore\Sitecore Client Authoring");
AuthenticationManager.Login(scUser);

string url = "/sitecore/shell/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor.aspx?id=%7b110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9%7d&amp;la=en&amp;fo=%7b110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9%7d";
url = string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) ? "/" : url;

HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url, false);
```

But it always redirects the user to sitecore/login page.

Any idea what is the issue here?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I'm not entirely sure that approach is a supported scenario. However, the Content Editor runs off the "shell" website, possibly that is your issue.

Try putting this code around your entire code block.

```
using(new SiteContextSwitcher("shell")) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

`AuthenticationManager.Login(scUser);`

to

`AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(scUser);`